# In Bootstrap (version 5.3) when I copied my features from the examples why isn't the background getting copied?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Today, when I was working on a website with bootstrap I was copying the features from the examples in the bootstrap section. Then when I kept the code in my coding platform the background was transparent and did not come with a background why?

I was expecting to get a background along with the code so that the features won't be transparent

Well, here's my code:

```
<div class="container px-4 py-5" id="featured-3">
      <h2 class="pb-2 border-bottom">Why Choose Us?</h2>
      <div class="row g-4 py-5 row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-3">
        <div class="feature col">
          <div class="feature-icon d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-bg-primary bg-gradient fs-2 mb-3">
            <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em"><use xlink:href="#collection"></use></svg>
          </div>
          <h3 class="fs-2 text-body-emphasis">Easy to Use</h3>
          <p>So easy to use, that even your dog could do it.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="feature col">
          <div class="feature-icon d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-bg-primary bg-gradient fs-2 mb-3">
            <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em"><use xlink:href="#people-circle"></use></svg>
          </div>
          <h3 class="fs-2 text-body-emphasis">Elite Clientele</h3>
          <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="feature col">
          <div class="feature-icon d-inline-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-bg-primary bg-gradient fs-2 mb-3">
            <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em"><use xlink:href="#toggles2"></use></svg>
          </div>
          <h3 class="fs-2 text-body-emphasis">Guaranteed to work</h3>
          <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back. </p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please provide your code, and maybe more detail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think You may have copied the examples based on the Bootstrap official documentation of each component and many of the times bootstrap does not define the background color which triggers the default color which is white or Grey,etc and may be You also want to look onto this [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/background/#background-color) of bootstrap regarding the background colors in bootstrap and How to add it.
Hope this Helps.

And Welcome to StackOverlflow, Elaborate and provide more detail Next time onwards when You ask Any Question.